# Phaser: Key Down + Collision Kill

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, phaser-framework

Forewarning: semi-newbie

Basically, if the user has the left cursor down and a "token" collides with the lftRect, I want to kill the token. For some reason my kill callback function for the collision is not working (below is relevant code):

```js
gumballGoGo.Preloader = function(game){
    this.player = null;
    this.ground = null;
    //this.tokens = null;
    this.ready = false;
};

var cursors, lftInit, rghtInit, ground, testDrp, sprite, tokens, rect, lftRect, ctrRect, rghtRect, lftToken;
var total = 0;

function lftHit(lftRect, lftToken) {
    if ( lftInit == true ){
        lftToken.kill()   
    }
};

gumballGoGo.Preloader.prototype = {
    preload: function(){
    },

    create: function() {

        // LFT BOX
        lftRect = this.add.sprite(0, this.world.height - 150, null);
        this.physics.enable(lftRect, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
        lftRect.body.setSize(100, 100, 0, 0);


        // CNTR BOX
        ctrRect = this.add.sprite(100, this.world.height - 150, null);
        this.physics.enable(ctrRect, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
        ctrRect.body.setSize(100, 100, 0, 0);


        // RGHT BOX
        rghtRect = this.add.sprite(200, this.world.height - 150, null);
        this.physics.enable(rghtRect, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
        rghtRect.body.setSize(100, 100, 0, 0);


        // INIT TOKEN GROUP  
        tokens = this.add.group();
        tokens.enableBody = true;
        this.physics.arcade.enable(tokens);

        testDrp = tokens.create(125, -50, 'token');
        testDrp.body.gravity.y = 300;



        // CONTROLS
        this.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

    },

    update: function() {
        this.ready = true;

        if (this.cursors.left.isDown)
            {
                lftInit = true;
            }
        else if (this.cursors.right.isDown)
            {
                rghtInit = true;
            }
        else
            {
                lftInit, rghtInit = false;

            }

        if (total < 20)
            {
                tokenSpawn();
            }

        this.physics.arcade.collide(lftRect, lftToken, lftHit, null, this);    

    }
};


function tokenSpawn() {

    lftToken = tokens.create(25, -(Math.random() * 800), 'token');

    lftToken.body.gravity.y = 300;

    total++;

}
```

The ultimate goal is to [recreate this type of gameplay](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMzMsktgu0Q).

One additional note: as of now I am dropping "tokens" using a random spawn loop. I'd rather use a timed patter for the token drop. If you have any advice on that please share as well. Thanks :]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, so this is a guess, but you're applying the last parameter of 'this' to the function 'lfthit' that is outside of the gumballGoGo.Preloader.prototype object. What error are you getting in the console?